# Maximum Video Capacity of USB C when Connected to a Dock

Tags: usb, video, hdmi, displayport, usb-c

I am trying to understand the USB C format and all its different modes but it is starting to get a bit too confusing. I understand that USB C can support 4k at 60Hz along with HDR. From what I understand it achieves this by going into some sort of "alt mode" where all the channels are dedicated to video output. However is this still true when it is connected to a dock where it would also have to be passing things such as USB, ethernet, audio etc? I would guess that in this case that some of the channels would then be dedicated to data transfer in which case the port would downgrade its video capability? **So my question is specifically what would be the maximum screen size and refresh rate a USB C port supports when also connecting other devices?**

My specific scenario is:

- C49HG9x 3840x1080p display with HDR
- ThinkPad T14 with USB-C 3.2 Gen 2 (DisplayPort 1.4)

I would like to buy a dock that allows me to connect ethernet and USB devices but also allow me to use my screen at a decent refresh rate (above 30Hz) while also keeping HDR. Is this even possible with the capabilities of USB C or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connected to a dock over Type-C port, the link must support USB, by definition of a dock. If the dock features Display Port, some USB wires are used in so-called "Alternate mode".
There are two kinds of ALT-DP mode:

1. The Type-C connector gets configured as full-size 4-lane DP, the video performance (in current ver.1.4) is as a normal DP - 5k at 60 Hz, or slightly higher if DSC (digital stream compression) is implemented. In this case the link provides only USB 2.0 connectivity (480 Mbps).

[image]

2. The DP is configured as 2-lane, so the video capability is halved, to 4k at 60 Hz. But in this case the other two lanes are used by its direct designation as USB 3.2 SuperSpeed connection (plus USB 2.0 obviously). This allows for 1-GB Ethernet and a set of full-featured USB 3.x ports for peripheral expansion.
   [image]

For more details, see this [USB-IF-hosted publication.](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/D2T1-4%20-%20VESA%20DP%20Alt%20Mode%20over%20USB%20Type-C.pdf)

Comment: So what device decides whether to choose 4 lane or 2 lane if both technically work? Does the dock decide?

Answer (score 1):

Dan!

So to start off, I'm basing this on using a 2016 MacBook Pro 15" with 4 Thunderbolt/USB-C ports, since I've never used a Lenovo ThinkPad. I do believe the answers should line up.

I am connecting to an [AOC 4K UHD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07LBM2DCC) monitor and using a [dongle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MR1FUNV) since it doesn't directly connect via USB-C.

First, the full 4K support is there and the refresh rate is at its maximum supported output by the MacBook Pro, which is 60Hz. The monitor also supports 60Hz refresh.

I couldn't find a second generation [Lenovo ThinkPad spec sheet](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_T14_Gen_1_AMD/ThinkPad_T14_Gen_1_AMD_Spec.PDF), but based on the first generation one I found, it supports 3 external monitors via USB-C. With the dongle, I've achieved 2 external displays at 4K 60Hz.

I did find a ThinkPad specific Thunderbolt [dock](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd500265-thinkpad-thunderbolt-3-dock-gen-2-overview-and-sevice-parts) that allows USB/USB-C, Ethernet, and audio output. I do believe you can achieve the full 4K + HDR output you desire, but like I said, I'm basing this off a MacBook Pro with USB-C ports.

I hope at least this leads you to making a good choice on a dock.

Answer (score 1):

[USB C Alternate Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode)
does nothing else in your case than establish a path between your
display adapter and the monitor,
(almost) exactly as if the monitor was directly connected to the card.

USB-C contains four high-speed data-lanes, so can support four devices at
full speed.
This requires USB-C support all the way from the computer to the monitor via
the dock.

On the other side,
[DisplayPort 1.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#1.4)
has the capacity according to this link of
"4K UHD (3840 × 2160) at 120 Hz with 30 bit/px RGB color and HDR".

According to the specs you listed, and if all the conditions are fulfilled,
your computer will support 4k at 60Hz, that is if the dock supports real
USB-C connections.